# Logging into a website using java

Tags: java, autologin

I'm looking for a solution to login to a website using a java program.

I found a good script over here:

http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/blog/114/entry-2715-login-to-a-website-from-java/

But the trouble is with handling cookies? How can I get the cookie info. send by the server?
Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Handling cookies using the java.net.* API](http://www.hccp.org/java-net-cookie-how-to.html)

Comment: @ ayush, thanks for the help it helped!!!!

the method I was looking for was getHeaderField() of URLConnection class

Answer (score 1):

Check [JAAS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Authentication_and_Authorization_Service) , to use it for automatic log-in and if you are using IBM WebSphere check "Trust Association Interceptor"

Answer (score 0):

Use HtmlUnit Framework. or Apache httpclient framework.